# Is coefficient of static friction constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Do coefficient of static friction depend upon the objects if same surface is taken or will it be constant for any object ?

Comment: Which one is easier to slide - steel wool on a metal surface or ice on a metal surface?

Comment: Friction happens between _two_ surfaces that contact each other. The coefficient depends on the properties of both of them.

Comment: How do we know which one's the surface, anyway? Does a metal cube slide better on a steel wool surface or on an ice surface?

Comment: I think the other comments have answered your question.

Comment: There is no _the_ surface. The math doesn't distinguish between one that "wants to move" and one that "wants to remain stationary."